# Performing arithmetic operations on given columns data in Pandas using Flask

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, flask

To retrieve database values of the particular row back into the template (webpage) by doing some calculations. But I don't know how to get particular values from an SQL table and perform calculations.

So for this purpose, I tried Flask along with [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29). I stored some data in MySQL tables and was able to retrieve its content back into a Flask template in table format:

> geo = pd.read_sql_table('rsinputs', engine, columns=['province', 'county', 'depmin', 'inventory', 'geo', 'grades', 'asratio', 'dpbaux', 'deratingai203', 'deratingas', 'becol', 'bfcol', 'bgcol', 'bhcol', 'bicol'])

Yes, the output I got is DB tables, but now how do I perform calculations like some value from `province` + some value from the inventory?

Answer (score 0):

Yeh , i solved it by myself..

bf12 = geo['bfcol'].iloc[2]

geob = bf12+bf12